# how to use the command "for" in logo

Tags: logo-lang

I'm not sure how to use the "for" command in logo. Can you help me

‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎‎ ‎

Comment: You need to provide a little more info. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UCBLogo, MSWLogo or FMSLogo you can use **for** in this way:

```
for [i 2 10] [show :i]
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And if you want to use a **step** number you can do it this way:

```
for [i 2 10 2] [show :i]
2
4
6
8
10
```